# How to increase gitlab job concurrency on gke kubernetes runner?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gitlab, google-kubernetes-engine, gitlab-ci-runner

I created two gitlab runners through [the standard default runner creation UI in gitlab](https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2020/03/27/gitlab-ci-on-google-kubernetes-engine/) (3 node n1-standard-4 gke cluster). [I've been trying to increase my gitlab runner to handle more than the default 4 concurrent jobs, but for some reason the limit is still capped at running only 4 jobs at once.](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/blob/master/docs/configuration/autoscale.md#runner-global-options)

In GCP I changed the `concurrent` value in the `config.toml` from 4 to 20 under the config maps `runner-gitlab-runner` and `values-content-configuration-runner` that were generated in my cluster found under the https://console.cloud.google.com/kubernetes/config menu.

What else do I need to change to allow my gitlab runners to run more than 4 jobs at once?

[Do I need to change the `limit` in the runner options?](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/blob/master/docs/configuration/autoscale.md#runners-options) If so, where would I find that config in GCP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the config maps in GCP will not immediately update the cluster.  You need to manually reload the deployment with:

```
kubectl rollout restart deployment/runner-gitlab-runner -n gitlab-managed-apps
```

There is also a button in the GCP cluster menu that will pull up a terminal with the kubeconfig of your cluster in a browser window.